# Responsive CSS for table using VH to fit entire table on screen

Tags: html, css

I have a table that I'm working on that I want to fit the screen. Whether it's an iPhone, iPad, PC whatever. I want it to fit the window.

So far it all works besides I get a bug when I'm on a PC, and the window is half-screened. It acts as though the screen is wider. Thus showing like half of the table.

Here is a JS fiddle of what I'm talking about:

https://jsfiddle.net/16fyombn/1/

```css
img {
    height: 24vh;
    width: 40vh;
    object-fit: scale-down;
}
body {}
#loading {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 25%;
    left: -25%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.8;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 99;
    text-align: center;
}
#loading-image {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 100;
}
table td {
    position: relative;
}
.ui-effects-transfer {
    background: url("http://images.clipartpanda.com/finger-clipart-pointing-finger-md.png") no-repeat;
    opacity: .8;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-top: 9vh;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-size: 9vh auto;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!--- Basic Page Needs
   ================================================== -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>eTeacher.online</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
   ================================================== -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.6/hammer.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="width: 100vh; height: auto">
    <div id="container">
        <table id='table1' style="">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td id="{{$data['comparison'][0]}}" class="cell">
                        <a href='response/{{ $data[' comparison '][0]}}'><img class='trial' src='{{ url(' taskAssets/ '.$data['comparison '][0]) }}.jpg' /></a>
                    </td>
                    <td id="{{$data['comparison'][1]}}" class="cell">
                        <a href='response/{{ $data[' comparison '][1]}}'><img class='trial' src='{{ url(' taskAssets/ '.$data['comparison '][1]) }}.jpg' /></a>
                    </td>
                    <td id="{{$data['comparison'][2]}}" class="cell">
                        <a href='response/{{ $data[' comparison '][2]}}'> <img class='trial' src='{{ url(' taskAssets/ '.$data['comparison '][2]) }}.jpg' /></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td id="sample" style="border: 2vh solid #000;">
                        <img class='trial' src='{{ url(' taskAssets/ '.$data['sample '][0]) }}.jpg'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="{{$data['comparison'][3]}}">
                        <a href='response/{{ $data[' comparison '][3]}}' class="cell"> <img class='trial' src='{{ url(' taskAssets/ '.$data['comparison '][3]) }}.jpg' /></a>
                    </td>
                    <td id="{{$data['comparison'][4]}}">
                        <a href='response/{{ $data[' comparison '][4]}}' class="cell"><img class='trial' src='{{ url(' taskAssets/ '.$data['comparison '][4]) }}.jpg' /></a>
                    </td>
                    <td id="{{$data['comparison'][5]}}">
                        <a href='response/{{ $data[' comparison '][5]}}' class="cell"><img class='trial' src='{{ url(' taskAssets/ '.$data['comparison '][5]) }}.jpg' /></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

I am trying to get it to work on any screen and to fit. And when the screen gets resized to respond accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean "there's a bug when the window is half sized"? I can't seem to reproduce any kind of error. The table resizes to fit the height of the viewport no matter what size my browser window is.

Comment: Well its not an error. But when you manipulate the horizontal view of the window nothing changes. It only resizes when you resize the vertical aspect of your window.

Comment: Ah, okay, well just so you know, the unit for width is `vw`, not `vh`.

Comment: Added `#table1 { height: 100vh; width: 100vw; }` it works great.

Comment: Thanks that seems to work! But one problem arises. When I set it like that. it does not work. In fact what works is setting each picture size within the table to   img { height: 25vh; width: 25vw; } though the problem arises when i only shift my horizontal page, the table height doesnt down-scale too. I want it to be equal. So the table doesnt stretch. So when height or width is resized, the table hugs the pictures rather than be distorted.

Comment: Solved with height: auto; height-max: 25vh; thanks!

Comment: One of the issues hwoever, is when i do #table1 height: 100vh; width: 100vw; the pictures within the table don't resize. How could I get that done?